# Insert element into vector inside map C++

Tags: c++, containers

```
Sample::Sample(vector<Observation*> * vec_observations)
{
   this->m_observations = new map<int, vector<Observation*>*>;

   vector<Observation*>::iterator it;

    for(it = vec_observations->begin(); it != vec_observations->end(); it++){
      m_observations[(*it)->getMonth()]->push_back((*it));//ERROR LINE
    }

}
```

It throws the following error:

base operand of '->' has non-pointer type etc...

Regards

Comment: Use GCC 4.8 or a recent Clang. It will give you the exact position (column number also) of the error. BTW, consider switching to C++11

Comment: You're kind of lucky that the compiler give you error, because you have much worse problems than that in those few lines. You allocate a map where the data is a pointer. But if you don't initialize those pointers, where will those pointers actually point? In short, `m_observations[...]` will give you a null pointer.

Comment: Why all the pointers? You could simplify your life a great deal by not using them at all.

Comment: As for your problem, think about the type of `m_observations`.

Comment: New, new, new, new, *, *, *, *... Avoid all of that pointers, are not necesary at all.

Comment: University professor tolds us that pointers are adecuated when you are managing with large amounts of data, and this is a case of that.

Comment: Apart from all the comments, saying not to overuse pointers (which I agree with) and so on, your error comes from [] operator. m_observations is a pointer, thus you cannot call [] on it. try calling m_observations->at((*it)->getMonth())->push_back(*it);

Comment: No, your professor seems like not know C++ well (or you missundertood him). C++ objects manage data internally. Have you tried to see whats the size of a vector, or of a map? Just a few bytes. Thats because that enities manage its memory internally through constructors and destructors.

Comment: I think you misunderstood your professor. Check the value of `sizeof(map<int, vector<Observation>>`. It isn't huge.

Comment: Piotr Zurkowski gave the correct solution, if you want to post it in a answer, afterwards I'll mark it as best answer. Thanks

Comment: Without knowing the context, no one here can really tell you if your pointers are necessary or not. But it is very unlikely, that you really need them here.

Comment: @joakin8 There is no difference in size between `Foo* ptr = new Foo();` and `Foo obj;` (beside the 4 bytes for the ptr). However it makes a huge difference designwise. If you however dont know what your doing, objects can fast become a bottleneck (unecessary copies etc.). The thumb rule however is': Avoid pointers whenever possible. And this is such a case where you can easily avoid it.

Comment: Thanks very much for your advices, I'll consider change the pointers, everybody have been very helpful.

Comment: @joakin8 Just another thing which came into my mind. Maybe you missunderstood your prof: You MUST use pointers if you want to create objects dynamically on runtime. However, `std::map` and `std::vector` and any other collection will already do this for you under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m_observations` is a pointer to map, so using `[]` operator on it means you are trying to index into an array of `map<int, vector<Observation*>*>` and therefore `->` won't apply because you are dealing with a non-pointer. Change the line inside your for-loop to `(*m_observations)[(*it)->getMonth()]->push_back((*it));` and the code will compile.

Here is a [version](http://ideone.com/1NGgH4) that compiles.

Comment: Thanks man, is the same solution given by  Piotr Zurkowski, both have been very useful.

Comment: You are welcome. As others have mentioned, try to minimize pointer usage, it will reduce the possibility of bugs. Happy coding!